# Always on top behavior through a check box PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt4, flags

There is a lot of information on the "always on top" issue but I'm too   inexperienced to get through.
I want to have a CheckBox (aboveAll) on my window (which is QDialog) to toggle window's behavior from 'normal' to 'always on top'. The closest I get:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
class MyForm(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Kamipy()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.aboveAll.stateChanged.connect(self.ABOVE)
    def ABOVE(self):
        if self.ui.aboveAll.isChecked() == True:
            self.ui.setWindowFlags(self.ui.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        if self.ui.aboveAll.isChecked() == False:
            self.ui.setWindowFlags(self.ui.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
```

And it brings the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "kamimimi.pyw", line 17, in ABOVE
>       self.ui.setWindowFlags(self.ui.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
>   AttributeError: 'Ui_Kamipy' object has no attribute 'setWindowFlags'

is it because my window is a dialog (not main window)? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your window **is** a dialog. But you are not calling the methods of your window; you are calling the methods of `self.ui` - which, as the traceback tells you, is of type `Ui_Kamipy`, not `QDialog`.

The `self.ui` object is a just a simple python wrapper class that provides a namespace for the widgets you added in Qt Designer. When you call its `setupUi` method, you pass in an instance of whatever is the top-level class you created in Qt Designer. So in this case, the top-level class is `QDialog`, and you pass in the instance `self`.

So the window is `self`, and its child widgets can be accessed as attributes of the namespace `self.ui`. This means your code should look more like this:

```
from PyQt4 imort QtCore, QtGui

class MyForm(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Kamipy()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.aboveAll.stateChanged.connect(self.ABOVE)

    def ABOVE(self):
        if self.ui.aboveAll.isChecked():
            self.setWindowFlags(
                self.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        else:
            self.setWindowFlags(
                self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.show()
```

Note that I have added the line `self.show()` at the bottom, because [setWindowFlags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop) can cause the window to become hidden.

Comment: It's clear now. I had my code written right before posting this question, but disappearance of the window made me think that it's totally messed up. Thank you very much for this profound explanation! I would vote it if I could:-)